# Migration Data Unsaved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I put this in my migration file inside "def up)"

```
User.find(:all).each do |user|
    user.login = user.name
    user.save
end 
User.find(:all).each do |user|
    puts user.login
end
```

I know user.name is definitely not empty. For this piece of code, the second loop still prints out nothing. Any idea?

Comment: Its not clear to me, so if you would explain trying to do here? Further have a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html)

Comment: Could you post all your migration for better understanding of situation, please?

Answer (score 0):

The user might not have been saved, due to validation errors.

If don't want to deal with validation errors, you should use the bang version to save (`user.save!`). That means you'll get an error.

To prevent validations, you can define the model inside your migration.

```
class CopyUserNameToLogin < ActiveRecord::Migration

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  def up
    User.find_each do |user|
      user.login = user.name
      user.save!
    end
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end

end
```

Tip: use `find_each` to do get the users in batches, which will reduce memory usage.

Tip 2: You might want to use a transaction.